# IMU linear acceleration to Linear velocity

Tags: c++, ros, imu

Hi Im doing some UUV simulation in gazebo and have IMU that gives me 9DOF namely my data is

```
Cheader: 
  seq: 301770
  stamp: 
    secs: 6064
    nsecs: 844000000
  frame_id: "thrbot/imu_link"
orientation: 
  x: 0.018933040808
  y: -0.00209639450915
  z: 0.337785931366
  w: -0.941030185311
orientation_covariance: [0.0001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0001]
angular_velocity: 
  x: -8.94731200724e-05
  y: 0.000117146098958
  z: 7.81746250685e-06
angular_velocity_covariance: [1.1519236000000001e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.1519236000000001e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.1519236000000001e-07]
linear_acceleration: 
  x: 0.0865246576615
  y: -0.363323777859
  z: 9.79281330072
linear_acceleration_covariance: [1.6e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.6e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.6e-05]
```

I would like to get the linear velocity and some how use the orientation for less error when do the double integration. I also have some 3D Pose sensor. So Its underwater robot simulation. I mean I have the IMU data for the orientation so some how want to incorporate that in my integration when get the velocity values.  Any help?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to be able to do sensor fusion and localize your robot off that. In this case getting linear acceleration off an imu is exactly what [the ros ekf](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_pose_ekf) package is for. It handles sensor fusion and will return odometry data.

Comment: No. i want to get the linear velocity from IMU before any sensor fusion.

Comment: @Bob9710 can I ask for what purpose? Usually it would be best(and most accurate) for this info to come out the localization stack.

Comment: its for the UUV control(observer). i wonna control underwater vehicle in  gazebo simulation, and need real values for the velocity first

Comment: @Bob9710 if you just need *some* velocity value you can take the timestamp delta of two messages and multiply that by the acceleration. If you need *accurate* velocity you should be using the odometry based on the sensor fused data from the ekf. The velocity will grow to be pretty inaccurate over time, otherwise.

Comment: I would like to fuse IMU with the Pressure (barometer) . Can EKF handle that? and any recommended package(ros package ) for fusing IMU and Pressure data?